# YouTube Displaying Homepage Incorrectly

Tags: ipad, youtube

My girlfriend's iPad Mini has started displaying the videos on the YouTube app home screen incorrectly.

Previously the videos on the homescreen would display in rows, however now, despite the orientation of the device, the video displays at full width. It is almost like the app thinks it is on a phone rather than a tablet.

[image: YouTube app homescreen]

Is there any way to restore the rows of videos? I checked the settings and couldn't see anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to have been a problem with the YouTube app. Google pushed out a fix on Friday morning that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

They updated the app. I wrote 5 feedbacks to tell them that it looks stupid on an iPad. Do I have to scroll 2000 times to see my videos. Please write them 1000 feedback so that they revert to the old home page.